# Remove pidgin from notification / indicator applet

Tags: unity, 15.04, indicator, pidgin

For some reason I want to stick with Empathy rather than Pidgin and hence removed Pidgin from Ubuntu completely.

Now, I still see pidgin internet messenger under the mail indicator applet icon:

[image: Screenhot (Pidgin listed even when removed)]

Nothing happens when I click that option. Please help me remove it.

P.S.: Do let me know if more information is required

**EDIT 1:**  I used Synaptic to install

1. pidgin
2. pidgin-libnotify
3. pidgin-dbg

**EDIT 2:** Output from `gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.messages applications`

`['pidgin.desktop', 'empathy.desktop']`

Comment: Did you remove pidgin-libnotify?

Comment: @xangua, yes I did.

Comment: Post output of `gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.messages  applications`

Comment: ['pidgin.desktop', 'empathy.desktop']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, we know that you have `['pidgin.desktop', 'empathy.desktop']` entry on mail indicator applet, so that's mean you haven't removed `pidgin.desktop` yet. To do so, open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.messages applications "['empathy.desktop']"
```

**Using *dconf Editor***

1. Install [Dconf editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor/) [image: Install banshee]
2. Launch *dconf Editor*
3. Navigate to **com** > **canonical** > **indicator** > **messages**, and delete **'pidgin.desktop'**

[image]

4. **Log out and log back in to apply changes you've made**

Comment: Yes! I googled and did exactly that. Was about to ask you to post your response so that I may accept it as an answer.. Thank you.

Comment: No problem :) I am glad I was able to help !

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!(Copied from [Fabby](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15559258/)'s canned comment)